# How does sendgrid send emails with my email address without knowing my account information?

Tags: email, security, sendgrid

I recently entered my email for a contest and then proceeded to enter emails of my friends for extra entries. I was later notified they received an email from *my email address* telling them to join the contest. I was confused on how this was possible, one of my friends showed me a picture where it mentioned the email was sent via sendgrid.net. It seems like they're an email marketing company that the contest providers were using.

**Question:**

How were they able to send an email with my email address without my account details?

Answer (score 1):

Read the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321).  Do you see the part describing mandatory authentication there?  No?  You know why?  Because it ain't there.  Email is just broken like that.  So  if your email address is at gmail.com and the recipients were at gmail.com there would be some non-required validation going on via dnssec or whatever is popular these days and recipients would get a warning that sender is spoofed.  But if your email provider or recipient's email provider are not sophisticated enough there would be no warning at all.